# Why property "NewSession" in the activity Open Browser of RPA UIPath not working properly? I still can see the old values in the browser

Tags: automation, rpa, uipath

I am trying to open a browser with URL https://www.property24.com/. I am trying to pass the User required search input [Search TextBox] through the Input Dialogue box. I have selected the "NewSession" property from the open browser activity but when I run the program I see the old values, even the "Property Type" dropdown value is already selected. I have to manually clear the cache & cookies in order to test the program.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

As the **[Open Browser](https://docs.uipath.com/activities/docs/open-browser)** specifies. The **NewSession** property is only concepted as

> Starts a new session of the selected browser.

But what you are looking for is the **Private** property. That says:

> Open a private/incognito session.

I know it's a bit confusing. But **all you need is enabling that Private property** and you will have your fresh browser without old values now.